# "Javaee-endorsed-api-7.0" no se encuentra

Tags: java, netbeans

Buenos días el motivo de mi pregunta es sobre  un error que me indica neatbens  **javaee-endorsed-api-7.0 not found** estoy tratando de buscar información de como solucionar pero encuentro informacion es de  6.0 pero me funciona alguien me puede indicar como solucionar este inconveniente  o brindar informaciòn donde puede encontar informacion  estoy creando un proyecto web con **java web jee 7** la version del  neatbens es 8.2

Comment: Me paso lo mismo y lo solucione instalando el plugin EJB and Ear según Noman_ibrahim [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520464/javaee-endorsed-api-7-0-not-found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descargar el archivo jar y agrega esto a tu paht classpath: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaeeendorsedapi70jar.htm